# My formula is not pulling out all the info just some of it

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
Count of AppCI for CRITICAL 11-16 = COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        '2023-11-16_OPEN_CRI_HI_MED_issu',
        '2023-11-16_OPEN_CRI_HI_MED_issu'[Severity] = "CRITICAL"
    )
)
```

this is my formula

i tried a few things but for somereasonn, it will leave out key points that are needed

Comment: Severity may contains some dirty values